# Overall Percentage

Tags: formula, percentage

I'm trying to calculate overall percentage for a multi-step test. I know which step I'm on and how many steps there are total. I also know what percent of the current step is complete. I want to write a formula that calculates the overall percent complete.

An example would be:

```
Total Steps: 8
Current Step: 4
Percent Complete (for current step): 100%

The overall percent complete would be 50%
```

Comment: Is this programming related?

Comment: Language, platform......

Comment: It is programming related, it's language agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each of the steps have the same “weight”, then one complete step equals `1/numberofsteps*100` (or `100/numberofsteps`) percent (`1/8*100`, or `100/8` for the lazy, equals `12.5%`), and therefor naturally `100/numberofsteps*numberofcompletedsteps` is the current percentage for all completed steps (`100/8*4` is `50%`, ain’t that a surprise?).

And if the next step is partially completed, then it adds `percentageofcurrentstep/100` times the already known `100/numberofsteps` to the overall percentage – like, step 5 be 25% complete, so `100/8` (percentage for one complete step) times `25` divided by `100` (percent again), `100/8 * 25/100 = 25/8 = 3.125%` – so the `50%` of the first four completed steps plus the `3.125%` of the partial fifth step gives an overall completion of `53.125%`. (`100/8*4 + 100/8*25/100` a.k.a. `100/8*4 + 25/8`)